# java "Variable not initialized" on delayed complementary alternatives

Tags: java

Why do I get this vexing "Variable not initialized" compiler error, when this variable will have been initialized in any case ?

```
File[] files;
final boolean doItFirst = evaluateOnce();
if (doItFirst)
    files = listFiles();
changeDirectory();
if (!doItFirst)
    files = listFiles();

// next line is flagged error by the java 7 compiler, although files as in any case been initialized
if (files != null && files.length > 0 ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The compiler can tell that those two `if` statements each tries to assign to `files`, but it does not recognise that the two conditions are complementary. Regard it as a compiler limitation if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical reason is to do with the JLS rules on *definite assignment* for `if` statements; see [JLS 16.2.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.7).

These rules (and the others) state that v is not definitely assigned in

```
 if (c) {
    v = 1;
 }
 if (!c) {
     v = 2;
 }
```

but it is definitely assigned in:

```
 if (c) {
     v = 1;
 } else {
     v = 2;
 }
```

The bottom line is that Java decides whether a variable "may not be initialized" based on the application of some simple rules, not on logical deduction.

(The language is specified this way to avoid the need for the compiler to implement potentially complex and expensive logical inference.  This also avoids hypothetical portability problems if one Java compiler did a better job of inference than another one.)

---

For what it is worth, I would code the relevant part of your example as:

```
boolean doItFirst = evaluateOnce();
if (doItFirst) {  // or get rid of the temporary variable
    files = listFiles();
    changeDirectory();
} else {
    changeDirectory();
    files = listFiles();
}
```

IMO, this is better than pre-initializing `files` to a dummy value because it is robust against changes to the code that accidentally cause the actual initialization to be removed.

Comment: are you sure that you can compare boolean with `=` ? i think this is not correct `doItFirst = evaluateOnce()` for that i edit it!!

Comment: It was intentional (and correct).  But I've decided it is not the best way.  (Because ... clearly ... the meaning is not obvious.)

Comment: @LaurentG - Re: the JLS.  IMO, leaving it to compiler "smartness" would actually be a lot worse in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can tell that those two `if` statements each tries to assign to `files`, but it does not recognise that the two conditions are complementary. Regard it as a compiler limitation if you want.

Here's a suggestion:

```
if (!doItFirst) {
    changeDirectory();
}
files = listFiles();
if (doItFirst) {
    changeDirectory();
}
```

This way the sequence of method calls is the same, but your `files` initialisation is out of the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know that `if (doItFirst)` and `if (!doItFirst)` are complementary (as far as the compiler can tell, the value of `doItFirst` could have changed after the first condition and before the second). Therefore it can't be sure your variable will be initialized in all scenarios.

If you use an if-else condition, you would avoid this problem.

For example:

```
if (doItFirst) {
    files = listFiles();
} else {
    changeDirectory();
    files = listFiles();
}
```

I wasn't sure where to put `changeDirectory()`, since I don't know how it affects the `listFiles()` calls. If you want to call `changeDirectory()` in both cases, you might have to call it in both the `if` and `else` clauses (or put it before or after the conditions).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise your array :

```
File[] files = null;
```

Yes it is logic that you think that no need to initialise your array, but this is not correct, you are using `files = listFiles();` just in `if` block, without else, for that the compilator ask you to initialise you array.

```
if (doItFirst) {//if the condition is correct
   files = listFiles();//then your array will be desalinized
}//else your array is not initialise <<--------here is the problem
```